# Search in QField does not work

Tags: qfield

In the desktop QGIS it is selected that the layer should be searchable (see picture 1). However, the search in QField does not work see (picture 2).  Figure 3 shows how the data is available in the Desktop QGIS layer.

Where does the error lie?

The aim of the search is to find the municipality and the property.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like that, you haven't set up an appropriate field - e.g. "gemeinde" or "nummer" - or an expression - e.g. concat( "gemeinde", ' ' ,  "nummer" ) -  on 'Display' tab of your project properties.

In the current QField documentation it is poorly documented (https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/map-styling/#display-expression, https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/search/), but I've tested it and it looks like (and if I can remember good, it was better documented in some old versions of QField documentation), that QField use this 'Display' field or expression for searching an expression in its searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

by setting both parameters (layer "searchable" in project properties and "display" tab in layer properties) :

- it works on android (qfield 2.8.7)
- it does NOT work on iOS (qfield 2.8.3)

Comment: Please do not ask questions in the area reserved for answers.  I have edited your question out.